# Counting INSERT operation to a table with trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm student and beginner SQL programmer. I build forum in php and MySQL, for my database classes. I wanna use TRIGGER to count INSERT operation, when user write a post and I want to overwrite a record in my database table with actual number of his messages. Is that possible?

For example I've got two tables:
user (id, username, password, email, number_of_messages)
messages(id,date,user_id,subject_id,subject,content)

When user write a message I want run TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER activity
 AFTER INSERT on messages 
  FOR EACH ROW UPDATE INTO user(number_of_messages) ....
```

And I don't know what to do. Can you help me with that?

Comment: `update into`? no such thing. you probably want `insert ... on duplicate key`.

Comment: Why not make `number_of_messages` a computed column. It will always be up to date with the correct information. Or at the very least, just use a join or subquery in your select to count the number of items from the `messages` table.

Comment: I am going to slightly disagree with the currently expressed view on this; under certain circumstances this is a valid way to reduce database load for frequently polled calculations. To provide an alternative to what @MarcB said, and assuming the user must exist to have messages, you should be able to just do an `UPDATE `user` SET number_of_messages = number_of_messages + 1 ....` Note I did say slightly, whether your current circumstances make this a good idea or a case of premature optimization is greatly dependent on the traffic you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but it is not a good idea to track count of messages. You can count it each time when it is necessary by this simple query.

```
select count(*) message_count from `messages` m
  join `user` u on m.user_id = u.id
where u.id=<your user id> -- or where u.username = <your user name>
```

Comment: I would agree with this approach. In my opinion it is better to request and calculate data as needed rather than force a calculation and update that may not be necessary.

Comment: @gmiley Why would the operation not be necessary?

Comment: this would only be good for a small-scale system. for larger systems, you'd want to cache this sort of thing, which means op's trigger as one method.

Comment: @Uueerdo - Well, we do not know what this number is used for. If it is being displayed on a users profile, for example, what would be the likelihood of that number being accessed enough to have a significant increase in performance by updating every time a record is inserted as opposed to, effectively, `select count(1) from messages where user_id = 1;`? To perform an update, you also will need to lock the record, to perform a select, that is not necessary.

Comment: @MarcB, I never deal with blog systems thus haven't measured the metrics on production but IMO viewing user's message count seems more rare operation than posting message, also DML is more heavy operation than select, but, it is just my opinion.

Comment: We seem to have different expectation on how often the message count will be needed. It greatly depends on the design of the message board; I've seen plenty where the message count is almost always displayed right beside the users name; so pretty much for every message they post, their total post count is shown. "Caching" the total in the user row seems a much more effective way of caching than trying to maintain in memory so that it is only calculated once per user posting on a giving "page".